# how to join data in data flow

Tags: azure-data-factory

I've defined 2 streams, and I am trying to join them.

I'm unable to publish because I'm getting this exception:

[image]

My Join transformation seems very standard:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The `data preview` tab doesn't seem to work:

[image]

**What am I doing wrong? How do we join data in data flow?**

Comment: Make sure that both columns have the same type.

Comment: The error message is very clearly, it caused by the join expression  . You should first try to solve the error in Join,  please show us the join expression and error message, if you can, also please give us some data of your two dataset.